# No Eth for accounts of private network of `truffle develop`?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm developing a Solidity program. I started `truffle develop`

```
> truffle develop
Truffle Develop started at http://localhost:9545/

Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
(1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
(2) 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef
(3) 0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544
(4) 0x0d1d4e623d10f9fba5db95830f7d3839406c6af2
(5) 0x2932b7a2355d6fecc4b5c0b6bd44cc31df247a2e
(6) 0x2191ef87e392377ec08e7c08eb105ef5448eced5
(7) 0x0f4f2ac550a1b4e2280d04c21cea7ebd822934b5
(8) 0x6330a553fc93768f612722bb8c2ec78ac90b3bbc
(9) 0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de

Mnemonic: candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat

truffle(develop)> migrate
Using network 'develop'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x3bfa69d31cbe12e43f20204daaf24e764a084ade586c3b417099d2e2deccc8eb
  Migrations: 0x8cdaf0cd259887258bc13a92c0a6da92698644c0
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xd7bc86d31bee32fa3988f1c1eabce403a1b5d570340a3a9cdba53a472ee8c956
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Replacing TutorialToken...
  ... 0x56fb0c0933ee395055db66976427f050e24dadda018b113d8f0cc03dc7229043
  TutorialToken: 0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xf36163615f41ef7ed8f4a8f192149a0bf633fe1a2398ce001bf44c43dc7bdda0
Saving artifacts...
truffle(develop)>
```

Then I setup MetaMask to connect the Private network of `http://localhost:9545/`. However, I cannot do any transaction because the MetaMask account has 0 ETH? How to add some test ETH for development?

**Update**

I realized that the account created by metamask has different addresses than the ten test accounts created by truffle develop. How to import the test account into Metamask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup Metamask you have to import the existing account (I can't remember the exact wording of the option, but you'll figure it out) and then provide the mnemonic Truffle gave you: `candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat`.

Comment: This is no longer the case. If you import by private key it won't ask for the mnemonic. If  you don't see any eth in the account, disconnect from the local network and reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the Truffle test accounts into Metamask, you can start Truffle with a predefined set of test accounts using the `--account` option. Just specify your private key and the amount of Wei you want to start with.

> testrpc --account
>   "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY,300000000000000000000"

This will initialize your account with 300 ether. Note that you have to pass in your key, not the address.

You can specify multiple accounts with separate `--account` options.

Comment: Thanks, does `truffle develop` have the parameter of `--account` too?

Comment: No, I don't believe it does. But, I'm still using v3.4 and haven't looked at the changes in v4 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing testrpc/ganache-cli accounts to metamask, you can start testrpc/ganache-cli giving the metamask's mnemonic seed.

Here's how to do it :

1. Open metamask
2. click on the burger menu on the top-right corner of the pop-in

[Metamask main pop-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqTbo.png)

3. Choose reveal seed word at the bottom of the settings pop-in

[Metamask option bottom pop-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI7FC.png)

4. Enter your password. Seed words should been revealed then. Copy/paste them somewhere safe.
5. When launching testrpc, here's what you can use :

Here's what i use :

`testrpc -m "<seed words>"`

if you use ganache-cli, which is the new version of testrpc, that's the same :

`ganache-cli -m "<seed words>"`

This is what i personally use :

`ganache-cli -b 15 --debug -m "<seed words>"`

`-b 15` means i want 15 second block time. I put this to have some delay as on the main net. When deploying your contracts and making requests you won't have instant answer. If you want you can put decrement this number if you want some delay but not wait too much.

`--debug` will allow you to have some more information like the assembly instructions made when making a call. It can be useful to know what fails or where the contract instructions stops.

Answer (score 0):

After you run `Truffle develop` and the console prints out the 10 accounts along with the private keys, copy one of the accounts private keys then go to Metamask > Import Account > Select Type = Private Key then past the copied private key in and then you should see the account with ETH in it.

Note: All 10 accounts should have 100 Eth except the first that used a small amount of Eth to bootstrap the chain.